# For a $2 \times 2$ matrix having eigenvalues 1,1 will the matrix satisfy a two degree monic polynomial other than characteristic polynomial?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations, symmetric-matrices

For a 2 X 2 matrix (except the identity matrix) having eigenvalues 1,1 is it necessary for the matrix to satisfy a two degree monic polynomial (X-1)(X-K) for some real K (K is not equal to 1) (the matrix clearly cannot satisfy a monomial). 
For example, an identity matrix can satisfy X(X-1) (the identity matrix also has eigenvalues 1,1) but can we **always** find an *n* degree polynomial except the characteristic polynomial for all *n x n* matrices having a repeated eigenvalue.

Comment: If the  minimal polynomial of the matrix is $X-1$, it can. But this means the matrix is the identity matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The matrix must satisfy its characteristic polynomial, i.e. $(X-I)^2=0$.  If also $(X-I)(X-kI) = 0$, then their difference $(X-I)^2 - (X-I)(X-kI) = (X-I)(k-1) = 0$ so
if $k \ne 1$, $X-I = 0$ i.e. $X$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: So a 2 by 2 matrix with a single eigenvalue can only satisfy a single monic two degree polynomial i.e it's characteristic polynomial?

Comment: Unless it's a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, yes.